# Trying to produce message to a kafka topic for every iteration but looks like I end up sending no msg to consumer

Tags: python, json, apache-kafka, kafka-producer-api, confluent-platform

Not able to write message into kafka topic (producer) when calling kakfa produce class with a loop.

I'm very new to Python and Kafka. I'm trying to write a python program to write messages into a Kafka topic and produce so Kafka consumer can subscribe to that topic to publish the message.

I'm not sure what is missing in my program which restricts from writing the message to the topic.

Point to Note: I'm reading a JSON file and using a for loop to ready the key value. Then assign it to a variable and refer that variable with Kafka produce with arg for msg.

Attached is the Kafka producer program.

Input: Json_smpl.json

File Content:

```
{
"transaction":{
"Accnttype":"Saving"
,"Branch":"West"
,"id":"WS"
}
}
```

Program:

```
from confluent_kafka import Producer
import json

def acked(err, msg):
    if err is not None:
        print("Failed to deliver message: {0}: {1}"
              .format(msg.value(), err.str()))
    else:
        print("Message produced: {0}".format(msg.value()))

p = Producer({'bootstrap.servers': 'localhost:9092'})
try:
    with open('json_smpl.json') as read_j:
        data = json.load(read_j)
        get_data = data.get("transactions")
    print(get_data)
    for i in get_data:
        a = list(get_data.items()[0])
        p.produce(topic='mytopic12', 'myvalue #{0}'.format(a), callback=acked)
except KeyboardInterrupt:
    pass
p.flush(1)
```

Expected result: Message(JSON Key & Value) to be written to kafka topic for every iteration within the loop.

Actual Result: No messages in topic. so consumer is not receiving any messages.

Answer (score 0):

Your file has no `transactions` key, and no loop to go over, so your JSON isn't being parsed, and you are not catching a KeyError or ValueError

Start with this

```
p = Producer({'bootstrap.servers': 'localhost:9092'})
try:
    with open('json_smpl.json') as read_j:
        data = json.load(read_j).get("transaction")
        tosend = json.dumps(data)
        print("Ready to send : {}".format(tosend))
        p.produce(topic='mytopic12', tosend, callback=acked)
except:
    print("There was some error")
```

Comment: Thank you for the response. I'm still not able to steam this message. In the consumer program, I've subscriber to the the specific topic ('mytopic12'). When I execute the consumer program, it doesn't picks us the message from the topic subscribed. So now I'm not sure if there's any message within the topic or the way I've programmer the consumer is incorrect. For reference, this is how I'm subscribing to a topic.  
c = Consumer(settings)
c_offset = (settings['default.topic.config'])
c.subscribe(['mytopic12'])

Comment: I would suggest using the `kafka-console-consumer` or `kafkacat` commands to be sure and make sure you start from the earliest offset